# Ui defect mysterious horizontal lines while scrolling in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I got a page in that page I have div in which scrolling is there .. In internet explorer when I scroll up and down the mysterious horizontal lines appears where as in chrome no such thing happens , another mysterious thing in that when I zoom out to small, this thing does not happen where as when I zoom in  then this mysterious lines appears

Note: This happens only in internet explorer

Comment: show us your code or add fiddle or code pen

Comment: You really should post the code you are using that causes the effect you mention.

Comment: Sounds like your browser might just be overloaded with data. haw large is your web page to download? You might have lots of things going on at the same time and the browser is having trouble loading them.